# Error al guardar un excel con PHP excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estoy intentando modificar una plantilla de excel mediante php y al momento de intentar guardar el archivo me envía este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Invalid cell coordinate
>   CHUY1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SiGGa\lib\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:594 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SiGGa\lib\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php(651):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('CHUY1') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SiGGa\lib\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php(624):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::absoluteCoordinate('CHUY1') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SiGGa\lib\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Workbook.php(323):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::absoluteReference('CHUY1') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SiGGa\lib\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Workbook.php(300):
>   PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Workbook->writeDefinedNameForNamedRange(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter),
>   Object(PHPExcel_NamedRange)) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SiGGa\lib\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Workbook.php(269):
>   PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Workbook->writeNamedRanges(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter),
>   Object(PHPExcel)) #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SiGGa\lib\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Workbook.php(75):
>   PHPExcel_Writer in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SiGGa\lib\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line
>   594

El codigo que utilizo es el siguiente

```
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    //Creamos un objeto para leer el archivo
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    //Cargamos el archivo a leer
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('Presupuestos_Creados/CALSONIC - NMX A1/Plantilla/FORMATO DE PRESUPUESTO CALSONIC.xlsx');

    //Moodificaciones a la pestaña 1 del archivo excel
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    //Modificamos la plantilla
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B7","Proyecto");


    //Creamos un objeto para escribir en el archivo excel
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');

    //Guargamos el archivo en la ruta especificada
    $objWriter->save('nuevo_archivo.xlsx');
```

Anteriormente ya había utilizado este código con otras plantillas y me había funcionado pero con esta en especia me envía ese error

espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Creo que te faltan unas comillas en "Proyecto", ¿o que tienes guardado en esa constante?

Comment: si es un error de dedo al copiar el código pero eso no es lo que me genera el error de arriba, de hecho puedo quitar la linea en la que modifico la plantilla y aun asi marca el error